# Unix: How to combine separate columns into one column

Tags: linux, unix

I created a script that logs if an email is sent if it satisfies a condition.

I get the output below using AWK to get specific columns.

[AUTORESTART] Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022

I want to convert them to csv so I use below command

```
cat logchkmail_all.txt | awk '{print $4,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' | awk 'NR>1{$1=$1}1' OFS="," > sample.csv
```

...which works, but it returns

[AUTORESTART],Mar,17,21:21:32,GMT,2022

as it should. But what I want is to be able to separate the [AUTORESTART] and then combine columns 6-10 so that it would just have a total of 2 columns, one with [AUTORESTART] and the other "Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022" as one column.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put in string literal inside `awk` print command.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat a
1 2 3 [AUTORESTART] Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022
$ cat a | awk '{print $4 "," $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10}'
[AUTORESTART],17 21:21:32 GMT 2022
```

You can see that I print 4th column, then a literal comma, then 6th column, then literal space, and so on until 10th column

You can then redirect it to a csv file

```
$ cat a | awk '{print $4 "," $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10}' > mycsv.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work? At least if you don't need it all in one piped command:

```sh
newstring=`echo $mystring | cut -d' ' -f1`
newstring="$newstring,`echo $mystring | cut -d' ' -f2-`"

echo $newstring # prints out [AUTORESTART],Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022
```

Comment: would this work if the input variable $mystring is multiline log?

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `sed` for this case because your only want to replace the first white space:

```sh
echo '[AUTORESTART] Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022' | sed 's/ /,/'
```

```
[AUTORESTART],Mar 17 21:21:32 GMT 2022
```